# Filebeat send mulltiline postgres log as one log to filebeat set only to this specific source

Tags: filebeat

For example i have some `sql` log:

```
< 2019-03-13 09:50:50.431 CET >WYRAŻENIE:  SELECT
                              SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column1, column2, ... ASC|DESC;
< 2019-03-13 09:58:50.943 CET >UWAGA:  detail: RUCH_KRADZ, 0.05, sum: 0.25, date: 2019-03-03
```

In kibana each line is a seperate log.
In filebeat i have:

```
  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
    - /opt/tomcat/logs/*.json
    - /var/lib/psql/logs/*
```

I want that only for the `/var/lib/psql/logs/*` the log should be as one beetween date. So in the example above we should have 2 logs in Kibana, not 5 - that is number of lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In filebeat configuration you can define multiple input sections each sections can have its own options

`multiline.pattern` Specifies the regular expression pattern to match, Where the first line of the message begins with a bracket (`<`)

```
filebeat.inputs:

- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /opt/tomcat/logs/*.json

- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/lib/psql/logs/*
  multiline.pattern: '^<'
  multiline.negate: true
  multiline.match: after
```

Check here for more details about [Manage multiline messages](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html#multiline-examples)